# How do I add custom entities to Typo3 CMS?

Tags: customization, backend, typo3-6.2.x

In my project I need to add a lot of custom entities to Typo3 CMS.

Eg. I need to have Buildings, Building Companies, Architects, Certifications, and so on.

What is the common approach for doing this?
Should I develop a new extension?

How can I then have a custom backend for managing these entities? Eg. in the Buildings admin page I want to be able to add a new Building also associating one or more Architects to it. Is it feasible? How?

Can I create a custom backend field for looking up Architects in the Buildings admin page? (eg. something like StackOverflow tags system, a token input field which looks up for items in Architects table in real-time while editing a Building)

Answer (score 0):

To map a business model into Typo3 I prefer to build an extension for that.

On the one hand you have the maximum flexibility by programming in PHP with the help of the Typo3 framework and on the other hand most of the backend management pages come in easy when using the standard MVC + TCA structure of Typo3 Extbase extensions (if it is your first try with Extbase you might want to have an Extbase book at hand).

You can have a look at the [Typo3 TCA page](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Index.html) to see which standard backend field types are available - there are shown a lot of example configurations. As in your case you might want to use a select field with property "size" > 1 and property "maxitems" > 1 to describe the relation between buildings and architects. As for the architects filter feature you might also want to add the property "enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield" as shown in [this example](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#multiselectfilteritems).